# Are the contents of $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] always English characters

Tags: php, filter

I have looked for a list of all $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] but could not find one that was robust.  I want to know if the contents of the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] are always unicode English characters, so that I can strip high AND low level bytes from the string before I evaluate it.

such as:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = filter_var($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW);
          $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = filter_var($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

Do any foreign browsers use local language characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: I would not consider HTTP header strings as Unicode at all, even for the subset where USASCII and  Unicode are the same.

Second: It's more important to ask what kind of user agent strings are allowed, not what is currently been used, as this can change tomorrow.

Citing https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.4

> Historically, HTTP has allowed field content with text in the
> ISO-8859-1 charset [ISO-8859-1], supporting other charsets only
> through use of [RFC2047] encoding.  In practice, most HTTP header
> field values use only a subset of the US-ASCII charset [USASCII].
> Newly defined header fields SHOULD limit their field values to
> US-ASCII octets.  A recipient SHOULD treat other octets in field
> content (obs-text) as opaque data.

In that regard, I would not rule out a potential browser with a `SüperBrøwser` user agent name, which would be mangled by `FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH`.

This is reinforced by an [earlier section](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3):

> A recipient MUST parse an HTTP message as a sequence of octets in an
> encoding that is a superset of US-ASCII [USASCII].